# Getting error 405 method not allowed when calling CreateDirectConversationAsync

Tags: c#, botframework

Any attempt to call the methods

```
Task<ConversationResourceResponse> ConnectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(ConversationParameters)
Task<ConversationResourceResponse> ConnectorClient.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(ChannelAccount, ChannelAccount)
```

Against endpoint: http://email.botframework.com/

fails with HTTP failure 405 method not allowed.

Code snippet

```
const string emailServiceUrl = "http://email.botframework.com/";
ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(emailServiceUrl));

ChannelAccount botAccount = new ChannelAccount("bot@mail", null);
ChannelAccount userAccount = new ChannelAccount("user@mail", null);

var conversationId = await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(botAccount, userAccount);
```

I could not find any documentation that indicated the exact email channel endpoint, so I used the endpoint [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/routing.html), that looked like it was for skype, and replaced `skype` with `email`. I noticed the caveat about not relying on the serviceUrl being stable, but I'm not sure what to pick if I'm trying to start a new conversation without any incoming message. If that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add trusted service url :

```
MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);
```

After that, your constructor should be :

```
 var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceUrl), microsoftAppId: appdId, microsoftAppPassword: appPassword);
```

Comment: I found this to be true as well, however it doesn't work for my scenario as I'm trying to do cross channel communications. Thanks!